# Rounded corner design not showing in png

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I am working on the logo when I save it as a PNG, it shows sharp edges whereas it has curved corners.

Attached is an image of how it looks in illustrator vs. how is it as PNG.

Why the PNG has sharp edges, do I need to change the setting when saving/exporting?

[image: left in illustrator, right a png]

Comment: why is question downvoted?

Comment: Because of the way it is written, had to read it like three times to understand, as the sentence does not really make sense.

Comment: @JulianSteinmann I have updated and revisited it as English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just pixelated... Export it in higher resolution. For example put dpi to 1200 when exporting or increase the artboard size. You may also want to read about the difference of pixel and vector based images.

Comment: I know difference between pixel vs vector but didn't know dpi impacted this as I do not have much knowledge of dpi

Comment: @localhost dpi is just another way to say more pixels. A 4 pixel round does not really differentiate easily. Anyway we should really just stop talking of ppi/dpi altogether as its mostly unnecceserily conplex way of expressing things for stuff that never sees print.

Comment: Yeah dpi for digital images is a weird thing to wrap your head around.